# How to split a output of a command into an array in shell scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, centos

I have executed a command that generated data in the form

```
111111
222222
333333
444444
555555
```

I have defined a variable in the command and just echo that variable which procedure this data

now I want to store this data into an array, in shell scripting

```
my_array[0]=111111
my_array[1]=222222
.....
so on
```

like this

I have tried a couple of things but all of them are storing index[0]. I want to perform some arithmetic operations on this data that why I want it into an array form.

```
 my_array=()
 select sum(a1) sum , date(create_timestamp)  date from student where date(create_timestamp) >= 'YYYY-MM-DD' and  date(create_timestamp) <= 'YYYY-MM-DD' group by date" | sed '1d'| while read sum date; do
        # echo $sum
        # echo $date
        my_array=( "$sum" )
         echo $my_array
#        echo ${my_array[0]}
done
```

Comment: Please, don't post data or code as images. Use the code formatting and paste them as text.

Comment: please update the question with the 'couple of things' you tried

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `my_array+=( "$sum" )` to add elements rather than overwrite the whole array, but if you trust the output format, why not assign it all at once instead of using a `read` loop?

```
mapfile -t my_array < <( 
 select sum(a1) sum , date(create_timestamp) date
   from student 
   where date(create_timestamp) >= 'YYYY-MM-DD' 
     and  date(create_timestamp) <= 'YYYY-MM-DD'
   group by date" | sed '1d' 
)
```